# YAML::Node operator= and reference behaviour

Tags: yaml, yaml-cpp

I'm a little confused about the semantics of node assignment in yaml-cpp. I was assuming there was automatic reference counting built into the Node class, but now I'm not so sure.

Can anyone explain the following to me (note the scope in which the 'temp' node is declared):

```
auto content = std::string{ "Test Scalar" };

// Case [1]
YAML::Node n1;
{
    YAML::Node temp(content);
    n1[content] = temp; // Assign temp node as map value
} // <temp local variable destroyed here>

std::cout << YAML::Dump(n1) << std::endl; // No problem

// Case [2]
YAML::Node n2;
{
    YAML::Node temp(content);
    n2[temp] = 1;       // Use temp node as map key
} // <temp local variable destroyed here>

std::cout << YAML::Dump(n2) << std::endl; // Crash, key node memory has been freed

// Case [3]
YAML::Node n3, n4;
{
    YAML::Node temp(content);
    n3[content] = temp; // Assign temp node as map value
    n4[temp] = 1;       // Use temp node as map key
} // <temp local variable destroyed here>

std::cout << YAML::Dump(n3) << std::endl; // No problem
std::cout << YAML::Dump(n4) << std::endl; // No problem!!
```

Why is [1] okay, but [2] is not?

It appears that in [3], the assignment of temp to n3[content] prevents the node data referenced by the temp local variable being deallocated when temp is destroyed. So it would seem that the Node class does reference count, but the count is not incremented when a node is used as a map key. Am I misunderstanding something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in yaml-cpp, which is now fixed. You were correct, in that it should not crash in any of those cases.

See [the issue](https://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/issues/detail?id=256) on the project page.

Comment: I had thought it was too obvious to be a bug, especially since I'm new to yaml-cpp and could easily have been using it incorrectly. Anyway thanks, impressive bug fixing efficiency!